# REST Request don't work

Tags: python, http

If I send a REST request from POSTMAN with followed body:

```
{"mode":"sync","messageType":"2fc4af5d7543ff1f22a9","messages":[{"timestamp":12345,"Brightness":12345,"Temperature":23456,"Humidity":345678}]}
```

It works fine.
But if I try to send it from python:

```
import os
import glob
import time
import requests
import json
import string
import datetime
import time

url = 'http://...'
dev = 'c46e9512-9358-4046-ba88-7b78b0d282d0'
authStr = 'Bearer ....'
url = url + dev

headers = {"Content-type": 'application/json;charset=utf-8', "Authorization": authStr}


dt = int(time.time())  #dt= 1479901984
data = '{"mode":"sync","messageType":"2fc4af5d7543ff1f22a9","messages":[{"timestamp":1029283,"Brightness":999.0,"Temperature":16.3,"Humidity":80.9}]}'

r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)

print r.text
print "status code = ", r.status_code
```

it looks very strange:
I receive a response with Status 200 (without body) and server side it don't work.
And more: if I change the message body, that it isn't correct (so I should receive an error) I still receive a response with status 200. It seams  the body is ignored:(
The URL and Headers are in both requests the same.

What is wrong?

Comment: What happens when you do not use a string as data, rather a dict and use post like this - requests.post(url, json=your_data_dict, headers=headers)

Comment: Please post the code as text and not as a screenshot. You can set invalid values for the url and auth tokens if you want. Also, a HTTP trace would certainly be helpful, with fiddler or such.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I have tried with the json and hasn't change anything:(

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be the root cause, but I wonder is it because the Content-type key in your header should actually be: Content-Type (capitalized T)? Can you try?

Comment: I have changed Content-type to Content-Type - no effect:(